# Java JUNIT ERROR

Tags: java, junit

I am using JUNIT to produce a test suite on a triangle project named (TriangleClassifier.java) and I am trying to read the below method that is to test the a,b,c sides and the expected output based on those values and then apply this to JUNIT although does not accept my test code and produces the following error. Any suggestions? thanks

JUNIT Error

```
expected: java.lang.String<ISOSCELES> but was: TriangleClassifier$TriangleType<ISOSCELES>
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
    at TestSuite.test1(TestSuite.java:9)
```

Method trying to test

```
  public static TriangleType classify (int a, int b, int c) {
        if (isInRange(a) & isInRange(b) & isInRange(c)) {
            if (isTriangle(a, b, c)) {
                if (a == b & b == c) {
                    return TriangleType.EQUILITERAL;
                } else if (a !=b & a != c & b != c) {
                    return TriangleType.SCALENE;
                } else {
                    return TriangleType.ISOSCELES;
                }

            } else {
                return TriangleType.NOT_A_TRIANGLE;
            }
        } else {
            return TriangleType.OUT_OF_RANGE; 
        }
    }
```

TestSuite.java

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;


public class TestSuite {

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        assertEquals("ISOSCELES", TriangleClassifier.classify(100, 100, 1));
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

Have tried your suggestions of changing 
       assertEquals("ISOSCELES", TriangleClassifier.classify(100, 100, 1));
to
assertEquals(TriangleType.ISOCELES,TriangleClassifier.classify(100,100,1));

ALTHOUGH my JUNIT now produces a new error - Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: 
java.lang.RuntimeException
    at TestSuite.test1(TestSuite.java:9)

**AND**

the below line where TriangleType is flaging an error with cannot find symbol - assertEquals(TriangleType.ISOCELES,TriangleClassifier.classify(100,100,1));

[ERROR Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqltC.png)

[public enum TriangleType](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhfwH.png)

Comment: Did you read the error message carefully? What part of it didn't you understand?

Comment: Well I have tried a few variations. by applying this assertEquals(TriangleType.ISOCELES, TriangleClassifier.classify(100,100,1));

Comment: COMMENT CONT - my JUNIT would produce a new error - Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: <any>
java.lang.RuntimeException
 at TestSuite.test1(TestSuite.java:9)

Comment: OK, where is the `TriangleType` enum defined?  Is it an inner type of some other type?  And what is its access modifier?

Comment: I have provided a screenshot of the public enum TriangleType

Comment: So it looks like you've defined `TriangleType` inside another class.  That means that within your test, you need to refer to it using the name of that other class, for example `OtherClass.TriangleType.ISOSCELES`.

Comment: You do **not** create screen shots of code. You **edit** your question and add the code. Hint: there is a lot of information at the [help]; you want to really study that. It starts with simple things: we have a preview function here. You don't drop messy code or links to screenshots on us - you sit down and put in nicely formatted/indented code to look at. You expect us to spend our time to help; so you please spend the time to come up with proper input.

Comment: Please stop removing your code from the question.  As I said before, it makes the whole question meaningless.  You need to keep it here, to possibly make this useful for other people.  Stack Overflow is NOT JUST FOR YOU!   Please put it back.

Answer (score 2):

By writing

```
assertEquals("ISOSCELES", TriangleClassifier.classify(100, 100, 1));
```

you tell JUNIT, that you expect the function to return the String "ISOSCELES". What your function actually returns is the constant TriangleType.ISOSCELES.
Change your assertion to

```
assertEquals(TriangleType.ISOSCELES, TriangleClassifier.classify(100, 100, 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your assertion is comparing a `String` to a `TriangleType`, so naturally, these won't be equal.  You want to write

```
assertEquals(TriangleType.ISOSCELES, TriangleClassifier.classify(100,100,1));
```

which compares a `TriangleType` to a `TriangleType`.

**Update**

Since it appears that you've defined `TriangleType` as an inner type of `TriangleClassifier`, you will *either* need to add an import statement for it to your class, *or* refer to it as

```
assertEquals(TriangleClassifier.TriangleType.ISOSCELES, TriangleClassifier.classify(100,100,1));
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have tried this and now my JUNI produces a new error - Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: <any>
java.lang.RuntimeException
 at TestSuite.test1(TestSuite.java:9)

Answer (score 0):

Without going too deeply into your algorithms, the error is most obviously highlighted by the return type of your `classify` method contrasted against your unit test. `classify` returns a `TriangleType` enumeration, but your JUnit test is expecting an object of type `String` to be returned. Since the two types are not equivalent, the expected and actual values cannot be equal. Hence the test fails.

Either change your test to expect a `TriangleType`, or your `classify` method to return a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Two things here:

1. You really have not much of a clue what you are doing. When you are on such a level that simple compiler error messages prevent you from making progress, you probably have to step back and focus on learning the java basics again before overburdening yourself with unit-testing and such things (although unit tests are a great thing, and one should start using them as early as possible).
2. Then I would suggest that you stop using assertEquals.

JUnit has another assert, called assertThat. You can use that like:

```
assertThat(TriangleClassifier.classify(100,100,1), is(TriangleType.ISOSCELES));
```

... and here the compiler would already give you a hint that

```
assertThat(TriangleClassifier.classify(100,100,1), is("some string"));
```

is invalid.

Further reading on *assertThat*/*is*: [here](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Matchers-and-assertthat)